# protractor can not find element with id

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

I'm using protractor and i can not understand why when i try to get something by css it works but if i try to get it with id it does not work.

Error message on the btnLogin line

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Some part of the code

```
browser.get('http://localhost:3000/#!/signin');
expect(element.all(by.css('.btn-social')).count()).toBe(2);
expect(element(by.id('btnLogin').count())).toBe(1);
```

if i try to do something in a input it works

```
element(by.id('username')).clear().sendKeys('something');
```

html of button

```
<button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `count()` on an `ElementFinder` - the result of `element()` call.

Instead, if you really want to check the count, you need `element.all()`:

```
expect(element.all(by.id('btnLogin').count())).toBe(1);
```

Comment: count was a typo. Should be outside of element finder of course :)
I though count worked for element also ...
I should check the doc more often i guess THX !!